# R: select top products in groups

Tags: r

I need to select 3 top selling products in each category, but if category dose not have 3 products I should add more products from best available category ("a" being the best category, "c" worst).

Every day the products change so I would like to this automatically. Previously I did choose top 3 products and if there was not available I did not bothered, but unfortunately the conditions changed. For that I used code as follows:

```
Selected <- items %>% group_by(Cat) %>%  dplyr:: filter(row_number() < 3) %>% ungroup
```

Sample data:

```
items <- data.frame(Cat = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
                    ranking = 1:15)
```

Desired results:

```
"a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"
```

Sample data - 2:

```
items <- data.frame(Cat = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
                    ranking = 1:15)
```

Desired results - 2:

```
"a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"
```

Comment: Not clear. Why do you only have 4 `c` if you want the top 5?

Comment: I want top 3. my bad. Edited. Sorry!

Comment: Then in your 2nd example shouldnt you have `a, a, a, b, c, c, c, c, c`? What constitutes the *best available category*?

Comment: No, if it is possible to add product from higher category (a - highest, c - lowest) then those should be added

Comment: So best category = highest category?

Comment: yes. exactly. The a is the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible answer. I'm not entirely sure if I'm getting what you are after - if not let me know.

```
items <- data.frame(Cat = c("a", "a", "a", 
                            "b", "b", 
                            "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
                    ranking = 1:15)
```

First we order the data according from best to worst category and add the count number within category.

```
Selected <- items %>% group_by(Cat) %>%  
                      mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
                      ungroup() %>% arrange(Cat)
```

Then we can make the filter and fill up with remaining rows from best to worst

```
Selected %>% filter(id<=3) %>%   # Select top 3 in each group
             bind_rows(Selected %>% filter(id>3)) %>% # Merge with the ones that weren't selected
             mutate(id=row_number()) %>% 
             filter(id <= 3*length(unique(Cat))) # Extract the right number
```

This produces

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
     Cat ranking    id
  <fctr>   <int> <int>
1      a       1     1
2      a       2     2
3      a       3     3
4      b       4     4
5      b       5     5
6      c       6     6
7      c       7     7
8      c       8     8
9      c       9     9
```

The second data example yields

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
     Cat ranking    id
  <fctr>   <int> <int>
1      a       1     1
2      a       2     2
3      a       3     3
4      b       5     4
5      c       6     5
6      c       7     6
7      c       8     7
8      a       4     8
9      c       9     9
```

which seems to be what you were after.

Comment: It is exactly as I said I wanted. Thank you very much for that! It helped me very much (before I did it manually)